# AngularJS - ui-bootstrap pagination. Hide buttons on single page

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, pagination, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using ui-bootstrap pagination and I want to hide the pagination controls when all the results are contained on a single page. As you can see in the picture below there is only one page and the controls are still showing. It seems like it would be common sense for the ui-bootstrap team to include this natively in the framework. So I'm thinking that there might be a way to do this easily but I wouldn't know where to start.

[image]

Here is the code in the controller:

```
$scope.itemsPerPage = 5;
$scope.currentPage = 1;
$scope.maxSize = 4;
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="observedCars">
  <div ng-repeat="obv in observed['Observed CARs'] | startFrom:(currentPage - 1) * itemsPerPage | limitTo: itemsPerPage">
    <div class="carId">{{ obv['Display Name'] }}</div>
  </div>
  <ul uib-pagination total-items="observed['Observed CARs'].length" ng-model="currentPage" items-per-page="itemsPerPage" ng-change="pageChanged()" max-size="maxSize"></ul>
</div>
```

I'm hoping that someone has already done this same thing and can help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use data-ng-show for the ul tag like <ul uib-pagination total-items="observed['Observed CARs'].length"  data-ng-show="observed['Observed CARs'].length>itemsPerPage" ng-model="currentPage" items-per-page="itemsPerPage" ng-change="pageChanged()" max-size="maxSize"></ul>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use data-ng-show for the ul tag like

```
  <ul uib-pagination total-items="observed['Observed CARs'].length"  data-ng-show="observed['Observed CARs'].length > itemsPerPage" ng-model="currentPage" items-per-page="itemsPerPage" ng-change="pageChanged()" max-size="maxSize"></ul>
```

Comment: Aaahhhh that did it!  Thank you, thank you, thank you. I just learned something new. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it manualy by adding ng-hide:

```
<div ng-controller="observedCars">
  <div ng-hide="observed['Observed CARs'].length == 1" ng-repeat="obv in observed['Observed CARs'] | startFrom:(currentPage - 1) * itemsPerPage | limitTo: itemsPerPage">
    <div class="carId">{{ obv['Display Name'] }}</div>
  </div>
  <ul uib-pagination total-items="observed['Observed CARs'].length" ng-model="currentPage" items-per-page="itemsPerPage" ng-change="pageChanged()" max-size="maxSize"></ul>
</div>
```

This probably isn't the best way to do it and probably ui-bootstrap have a way to fix this, but I couldn't find it either.

Anyway, this way angular will check if there is only one element in there, if it's length is not 1 it will hide the div the same way it does when ng-repeat is empty.